# How can I use insertFromSelect(...) without 'on duplicate key update'?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.6

I'm modifying Createat.php, you can see [the source here](http://php.r3dcode.com/files/Magento/1.6/1.0/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Report/Order/Createdat.php).

Quick overview:

```
$select->from(array('o' => $this->getTable('sales/order')), $columns)
  ->join(array('oi' => $selectOrderItem), 'oi.order_id = o.entity_id', array())
  ->where('o.state NOT IN (?)', array(
    Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT,
    Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW
  ));
...
$select->where('o.channel_name IS NULL');
$adapter->query($select
  ->insertFromSelect($this->getMainTable(), array_keys($columns)));
```

So everything is good at this point. My sales_order_aggregated_created table now contains all "Website" sales totals.

```
$select->reset('where');
$select->where('o.channel_name = ?', 'Amazon');
$adapter->query($select
  ->insertFromSelect($this->getMainTable(), array_keys($columns)));
```

This is where my problem is, when I reset('where') and filter by another channel_name and try to insert new rows into the table the insertFromSelect() function is using "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" and overwrites the values inside table from the previous query.

Is there a $select->someFunction() that does not update on duplicate or where would I find the definition of insertFromSelect() function? Or, perhaps there is another way of doing this?

Comment: You're probably trying to insert a new record which has an existing primary key. Is there any way you can reset this in `$select`?

Comment: For those wondering where $select->...() methods are defined. I found it in here /Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

Comment: You may use insertOnDuplicate() the question is, what do you want. Do you want to override the data already inserted or add the row with a new key?

Answer (score 2):

`Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface` has a constant `INSERT_ON_DUPLICATE` which you can pass as a flag to `insertFromSelect()` to disable the default `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` behavior.

```
$adapter->query(
    $adapter->insertFromSelect(
        $select,
        $this->getMainTable(),
        array_keys($columns),
        Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INSERT_ON_DUPLICATE
    )
);
```

Comment: I know it is a late answer, but it answers the question for future references.